# Why is Mock.Setup not returning the object I've defined?

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I'm having an issue with Mock.Setup. I'm trying to configure a function call on an interface to return a specific object, however, the return keeps coming back null.  Here is the code I'm working with:

```
MyMockObject.Setup(x => x.SaveOrderFile(
    It.IsAny<int>(), 
    It.IsAny<string>(), 
    It.IsAny<FileStream>(), 
    It.IsAny<MyInterface>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(new ResultObject<string>("test", true, message: "hello"));
```

When I step through this, I find that ResultObject is null instead of instantiated with the values I've assigned in .ReturnsAsync.  I'm not sure if it matters, but note that MyInterface is itself a mock object when being hit in the test code.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please, show the code for how you use this mock object.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured out a solution:

```
Mock<MyInterface> myInterfaceMock = new Mock<MyInterface>();

MyMockObject.Setup(x => x.SaveOrderFile(
It.IsAny<int>(), 
It.IsAny<string>(), 
It.IsAny<FileStream>(), 
It.Is<MyInterface>(x => x.Equals(myInterfaceMock.Object))))
.ReturnsAsync(new ResultObject<string>("test", true, message: "hello"));
```

While this works, I'm not clear as to why.  I would think that using It.IsAny as I had it written originally would work since myInterfaceMock applies MyInterface.  If anyone would be able to explain why It.IsAny doesn't work in this situation, I'd greatly appreciate it!